# mismatch between the number of fields and the number of arrays

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pytables

I want to append list to a table in h5. when append the data directly, it was done;

`ts=[(datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 233, 856, 0.2355, 1.17692), (datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 192, 518, 1.27893, -0.60389)]
tab2.append(rows=ts)`

while append the data from source,

```
 tab2.append(rows=tarray)
```

it reports error

```
"rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object compliant with table '/test (Table(4,)) 'TestTables''. The error was: <mismatch between the number of fields and the number of arrays>"
```

while the tarray is got from the following expression.

```
ran_int=np.random.randint(0,high=1000,size=(nrows,2))
ran_flo=np.random.standard_normal(size=(nrows,2)).round(5)

dty=np.dtype([('Date','M8[D]'),('No1','<i4'),('No2','<i4'),
                             ('No3','<f8'),('No4','<f8')])

sarray=np.zeros(len(ran_int),dtype=dty)

sarray['Date']=datetime.datetime.now().date()
sarray['No1']=ran_int[:,0]
sarray['No2']=ran_int[:,1]
sarray['No3']=ran_flo[:,0]
sarray['No4']=ran_flo[:,1]

tarray=list(sarray)
```

I printed both ts, tarray and their types, and got the same information as following.

`[(datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 866, 536, -0.83165, 0.50131), (datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 14, 117, 2.11287, -1.09029)]
<class 'list'>
[(datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 233, 856, 0.2355, 1.17692), (datetime.date(2017, 5, 30), 192, 518, 1.27893, -0.60389)]
<class 'list'>`

It's not the problem of datetime.
I try to change the dty

```
dty=np.dtype([('Date','S26'),('No1','<i4'),('No2','<i4'),
                         ('No3','<f8'),('No4','<f8')])
```

and

```
sarray['Date']=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

In this situation, I got the same result. it is the same as above.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is enough to mark the answer that solved your problem. We don't put tags like [solved] in the title.

Comment: thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, it's the problem of sarray.

```
tarray = []
for s in sarray:
    s=tuple(s)
    tarray.append(s)
```

Comment: Right, the data for a structured array (recarray) is in the form of a tuple, or list of tuples.

Comment: /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~ I find it can run successfully without converting sarray.  I mean, the expression  "tab2.append(rows=sarray)" works. oh, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

So I have not used pytables a lot but according to there documentation and example you just pass the array.  The error "rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray" seems to me like it is trying to pass rows, try:

```
tab2.append(tarray)
```

I could be very wrong but it might just be something simple, did you try this?